# Which ITR form should I fill if I am a working professional who also invested in stocks?

Tags: taxes, stocks, income-tax, india

What ITR form (ITR-1, ITR-2, ..., ITR-5) would Indian professionals in private sector fill if they also did a little stock trading via Zerodha?
Also I did ***not*** do "intraday" trading ***nor*** I did "long-term" trading where I kept equity for more than 1 year.

I did short term trading but now I want to know whether ITR-1 would be right or not. I heard that ITR-2 should be better as it talks about investment gains/loss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should file ITR2 for short term gains